# SpaCy doesn't recognize money and countries as expected

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm working with SpaCy in order to extract the different named entities from a sample text. The problem is that SpaCy doesn't recognize all the expected entities. It has problems with money and some locations. This is my code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load('es') #cargo el modelo en español.
text = u"Una vez un personaje le preguntó a Agustín Chirichigno si estaba en su casa. El nombre de este personaje es Lucas Picchi y es de Mar del Plata. Junto a SU PRIMO, DE ESTADOS UNIDOS hacen cosas re locas como por ejemplo comprar un Fernet Branca a AR$2.500 cuando en realidad está a $180."
doc = nlp(text)
displacy.serve(doc, style='ent')
```

Note that I'm loading a spanish model. My configuration is as follows:
spacy info

```
Info about spaCy

Python version     2.7.6          
Platform           Linux-4.4.0-112-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
spaCy version      2.0.9          
Location           /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy
Models             es, en
```

So, the output is:
[image]

What is expected is that SpaCy recognize `MONEY` correctly (AR$2500 is 2500 argentinian pesos and $180 is money too). The word "Junto" is not a `LOCATION` and neither "SU PRIMO". "Junto a su primo" would be like "with his cousin" in english. Also, Fernet Branca is a `BRAND`, and not a person.

So, my question is: what am I doing wrong? Should I use additional libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your model have BRAND in it?

Comment: How can I check it? I mean, there's no problem with that but I thought that MONEY is a basic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to spacy documentation of spanish model it supports identification of PER, LOC, ORG and MISC entities. It is trained on AnCora and WikiNER corpus.

In the release note it was mentioned that :

"Because the model is trained on Wikipedia, it may perform inconsistently on many genres, such as social media text."

As the results for your data are not satisfactory you need train it for your data. This can be done as suggested in [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner)

For money you can actually write a simple regular expression like this for american dollar money

```
^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$
```

Comment: Just to add that spacy has a [Matcher](https://spacy.io/api/matcher) object that can help with RegEx matching. One of the [examples](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#on_match) talks about adding NER annotations using a `Matcher`.